# Groovy: Adding multiple nodes to an a xml

Tags: xml, groovy

I am fairly new to groovy. I have an issue with adding multiple lines of nodes to an existing xml file. My xml looks like this.

```
<vehicles>
   <my:car>
      <ns:make>Honda</ns:make>
      <ns:model>Civic</ns:model>
      <ns:year>2012</ns:year>
      <ns:paint>
         <ns:color>red</ns:color>
         <ns:color>blue</ns:color>
      <ns:paint>
   </my:car>
</vehicles>
```

xml code to add:

```
  <my:car>
  <ns:make>Toyota</ns:make>
  <ns:model>Aygo</ns:model>
  <ns:year>2014</ns:year>
  <ns:paint>
     <ns:color>Blue</ns:color>
     <ns:color>Grey</ns:color>
  <ns:paint>
   </my:car>
```

The result should be like:

```
<vehicles>
   <my:car>
      <ns:make>Honda</ns:make>
      <ns:model>Civic</ns:model>
      <ns:year>2012</ns:year>
      <ns:paint>
         <ns:color>red</ns:color>
         <ns:color>blue</ns:color>
      <ns:paint>
   </my:car>
<my:car>
      <ns:make>Toyota</ns:make>
      <ns:model>Aygo</ns:model>
      <ns:year>2014</ns:year>
      <ns:paint>
         <ns:color>blue</ns:color>
         <ns:color>grey</ns:color>
      <ns:paint>
   </my:car>
</vehicles>
```

The code i have used is:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) 

holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("vehicles.xml#Request")

def toadd = '''
          <my:car>
          <ns:make>Toyota</ns:make>
          <ns:model>Aygo</ns:model>
          <ns:year>2014</ns:year>
          <ns:paint>
             <ns:color>blue</ns:color>
             <ns:color>grey</ns:color>
          <ns:paint>
       </my:car> '''

def root = new XmlSlurper(false, true).parseText(vehicles.xml)
fragmentToAdd = new XmlSlurper( false, true ).parseText(toadd)

root.find { it.name() == 'holder[“//*/my:car”]' }.children().add( 0, fragmentToAdd )


holder.updateProperty()
```

The added text toadd should be just under /my:car, I have seen examples of adding one node but not of a larger blok of nodes.
But it does not work. How can I make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your result-example the new block is a sibling to the existing `my:car` and in your later text you want to it to be "under `ns:paint`".  which one is it?

Comment: It should be under /my:car, I have edited that part. Sorry it was a mistake.

Comment: In the example above the <ns:paint> element must be closed using </ns:paint>.

Answer (score 0):

If want the XML to be well-formed then the namespace prefixes must be bound to a namespace.

```
def vehicles = '''
<vehicles xmlns:my="http://ns1.com" xmlns:ns="http://ns2.com">
...
</vehicles> '''
```

Once the vehicles and toadd strings are parsed into Nodes then can just call appendNode() to append new element to the first document as a new child element.

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(false, false) 
def root = slurper.parseText(vehicles)
def fragmentToAdd = slurper.parseText(toadd)
root.appendNode( fragmentToAdd )
```

Then print it out:

```
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```